# Addthis: Sharing for unique items on page

Tags: javascript, addthis

I am using addthis (addthis.com) to offer sharing on items listed on a page (stage.hverdagskupp.no).

Since each item on the page is unique, I want the shared information to be unique as well. However, facebook and twitter only seems to allow global page information to be shared.

Anyone knows how to define item specific sharing information with addthis, for facebook and twitter?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define what part of the page to share.  You only share links.  If you would like to share a different page than the current one, you can specify it in the link.
Check out http://www.addthis.com/help/url-and-title